# unable to append data to sharepoint file via Azure Automation

Tags: azure, powershell, sharepoint, runbook

Ok I have asked a question like this but now I am trying to perform the task via Azure Automation. I can connect to the SharePoint site via Azure Automation (powershell). with the correct credentials. I can download the file and append data to it. But I can when I try and upload the file back to SharePoint it adds the contents 3 times and then Azure Automation suspends the Runbook after 3 times.
It does run perfect if I upload this file as a different file name.

```
$siteurl="https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/teamsites/os"
$credSP = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'test'
$fileFolder = "$Env:temp"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteurl -Credentials $credSP

Get-PnPFile -Url "/sites/xxx/teamsites/os/Directory and Operating         
Systems/test.csv" -Path $fileFolder -Filename test.csv -AsFile -Force

$test = "31-07-2019 -11:35"

Add-Content -Path $fileFolder\test.csv $test
Add-PnPFile -Path $fileFolder\test.csv -Approve  -Folder "Directory and     
Operating Systems" #-ErrorAction Ignore
```

Here are the results
test test
31-07-2019 -11:35
31-07-2019 -11:35
31-07-2019 -11:35

As you can see it added $test 3 times.  But I dont have this issue if I upload it as a new file name.

Comment: I think I can fix this issue. Is there a way where I can stop the runbook after one run. So that it doesnt repeat itself 3 time >

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a while I have fix the issue.
After the add-pnpfile ......  you pipe it to |  out-null

Thats it. the sript stops after it uploads ,
happy days